# NodeJS send http request with absoluteURI

Tags: node.js

I'm working with a weird HTTP server that only accepts HTTP request which looks like:

```
GET http://10.0.0.1/test
Host: 10.0.0.1
Cache-Control: no cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

*Node the "http://" at the path*

When I'm sending HTTP request (using the code at the bottom) the request looks like:

```
GET /test
Host: 10.0.0.1
Cache-Control: no cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Code example:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'uri': 'http://10.0.0.1/test',
  'headers': {
    'Host': '10.0.0,1',
    'Cache-Control': 'no cache',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Any idea how I can send the request like the server expects using standard libaries?

Comment: What's wrong with the example you provided above? Are there any errors? If so, what *specific* errors are being thrown? What kind of software is running on this endpoint? Is there any documentation for its API?

Comment: The server side isn't at my control, it's some kind of legacy web server that expects "http://<server_ip>" before the path ("/test") for some weird reason